# How to use this variable in another file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on my project and i got problem that every time I try to import variable I get error. I tried lot of things but none of it works .Also i know that better not to use auto-generated code from pyuic but it's for time just to try something.So i need to import variable 'name_db' to antoher file  I recieve error "NameError: name 'name_db' is not defined".  Here's code

```
#logged.py                                                                                           from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from add_student import Ui_Add_student 
import sqlite3
import os, sys
import create
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from journal import *


class Ui_Logged(object):

     def add(self):
         self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
         self.ui = Ui_Add_student()
         self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
         
         self.window.show()
    
     def update(self):
         os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
     def open(self):
         
         os.system('python create.py')
         os.system('python journal.py')
        
     def setupUi(self, Logged):
         
         path = os.getcwd()
         only = os.path.join(path, r"db")
         
         onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(only) if isfile(join(only, f))]

         Logged.setObjectName("Logged")
         Logged.resize(337, 300)
         self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Logged)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
         #############################################
         self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
         #############################################
         self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(101, 80, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

         self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.update)
         
         self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
         self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 201, 41))
         self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
         self.comboBox.addItems(onlyfiles)
         
         self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 75, 23))
         self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

         self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.open)
         
         Logged.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
         self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Logged)
         self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 337, 21))
         self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
         Logged.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
         self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Logged)
         self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
         Logged.setStatusBar(self.statusbar) 

         os.environ['name_db'] = self.comboBox.currentText()
         
         self.retranslateUi(Logged)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Logged)
    
   
 
     def retranslateUi(self, Logged):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         Logged.setWindowTitle(_translate("Logged", "MainWindow"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Logged", "Додати учня"))
         self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Logged", "Відкрити"))
         self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Logged", "Оновити"))
        

         




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Logged = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Logged()
    ui.setupUi(Logged)
    Logged.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from datetime import date

def initializeModel(model):
   import logged

   
    

   model.setTable('sportsmen')
   model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
   model.select()
   model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Дата")
   model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Математика")
   model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Українська мова")
   model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Інформатика")
   
def createView(title, model):
   view = QTableView()
   view.setModel(model)
   view.setWindowTitle(title)
   return view



def findrow(i):
   delrow = i.row()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import logged

   path = os.getcwd()
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
   db.setDatabaseName(os.path.join(path, r"db/", name_db))
   model = QSqlTableModel()
   delrow = -1
   initializeModel(model)

   view1 = createView("Table Model (View 1)", model)
   view1.clicked.connect(findrow)

   dlg = QDialog()
   layout = QVBoxLayout()
   layout.addWidget(view1)

   dlg.resize(500,300)
   dlg.setLayout(layout)
   dlg.setWindowTitle("Database Demo")
   dlg.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You probably ignored it, but there should be a *clear* warning on top of the file you are editing, which says something like "don't edit this unless you know what you're doing". That's because editing pyuic generated files is a *bad* practice (for a lot of reasons): those are automatically generated files that are intended to be used ***only*** as imports. Please read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), as most problems derive from trying to edit those files (besides the problem pointed out in the current answer).

Comment: All the problems here are caused by randomly throwing things together in the hope that something might work, rather than taking the time to understand the basics first. You really need to work your way through a few [tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) so you understand how a typical PyQt application is put together.

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you define `name_db` as a variable global to logged.py nor as a variable belonging to the Ui_Logged class.

If you want to you could make `name_db` as a variable in your `Ui_Logged` class in logged.py as `self.name_db = ...` and then fetch it in your second file after import by creating an instance of your class `my_instance = logged.UiLogged()`, running the `setupUi()` method which creates the variable (unless you put it in an `__init__`) then accessing the variable with `my_instance.name_db`.

Alternatively, given you seem to be using environment variables currently, you'll have to fetch it from the environment again with `os.environ["name_db"]`, instead of trying to refer to a variable named `name_db`. The

If you do do this, the `os.environ[name_db']` line still isn't executed unless you run `setupUi()` first. Again an `__init__` would make this less of a problem.

So, if you're going with the environments route (I don't think it's a good idea but it's your program), try swapping `db.setDatabaseName(os.path.join(path, r"db/", name_db))` for `db.setDatabaseName(os.path.join(path, r"db/", os.environ['name_db']))` in the second file, and create an instance of the class + run that function prior to this line.

Comment: maybe I don't got it right but now it gives me this error:  "from logged import Ui_Logged
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_Logged' "

Comment: can you just import logged and then do logged.Ui_Logged? What IDE are you using? Any good IDE should make that kind of error trivial to solve

Comment: i'm using sublime text 3 and also when i use import logged it gives this error " db.setDatabaseName(os.path.join(path, r"db/", my_instance.name_db))
AttributeError: 'Ui_Logged' object has no attribute 'name_db' "

Comment: Because if your logged.py hasn't changed then no, it does not have an attribute with that name. Give Ui_Logged an `def __init__()` that sets self.name_db to =  whatever it is meant to be?

Comment: sorry for bothering you too much but i just can't get solution. if i creating def __init__ it's giving me this error "self.name_db = self.comboBox.currentText()
AttributeError: 'Ui_Logged' object has no attribute 'comboBox' "

Comment: Well yes, self.comboBox is defined in a *different method* that isn't executed at the time of instancing the class, so of course it errors trying to access variables that don't exist yet. Creating class attributes outside of an init is generally frowned upon but I'm not used to UI development so maybe this is normal here. You need to have the class's name_db attribute defined after all the parts that go into it, e.g. comboBox. You cannot ask for a variable that doesn't exist yet lol

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 no, even in UI development that's not a good choice anyway, unless you *really* know what you're doing. The problem here is just an attribute access issue (and improper use of automatically generated files that are *not* supposed to be edited unless fully aware of the consequences).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @musicamante